# Invert Binary Tree in C++

Tags: binary-tree, depth-first-search

I am working on LeetCode problem [226. Invert Binary Tree](https://leetcode.com/problems/invert-binary-tree/):

> Given the `root` of a binary tree, invert the tree, and return its root.
>
> #### Example 1
>
> [image]
>
> ```
> Input: root = [4,2,7,1,3,6,9]
> Output: [4,7,2,9,6,3,1]
> ```

I wrote the following C++ code, but it gives the wrong answer. I don't know whether there is a flaw in my logic.

#### Code

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    void dfs1(TreeNode* root,vector<int> &vec){
        if(root==NULL)
            return;
        dfs1(root->left,vec);
        vec.push_back(root->val);
        dfs1(root->right,vec);
    }

    void dfs2(TreeNode* root,vector<int> &vec,int &j) {
        if(root==NULL)
            return;
        dfs1(root->right,vec);
        root->val=vec[j];
        j--;
        dfs1(root->left,vec);
    }
    
    TreeNode* invertTree(TreeNode* root) {
        vector<int> p;
        dfs1(root,p);
        int size=p.size()-1;
        dfs2(root,p,size);
        return root;        
    }
};
```

I am just doing an inorder traversal and pushing the values into a vector. Then again I perform an inorder traversal, but this time I am traversing the other way, that is from right to left.

Answer (score 1):

Several issues:

- In `dfs2` you call `dfs1`... that seems not what you intended. You should call `dfs2`, and pass `j` as third argument.
- As you take values from the end of `vec` and walk backwards, you should not swap `left` and `right`, but still process `left` first, and then `right`
- But now comes the major blow: this algorithm never mirrors the *shape* of the tree, it merely replaces the *values* in the tree. So this can only work if the shape of the input tree is symmetric.

Because of the latter point you really need to use a different algorithm.

I would suggest an algorithm which traverses the nodes in any order you prefer, and swap the `left` and `right` values for each.

I'll provide here a hidden solution (spoiler) in case you cannot make it work:

> `TreeNode* invertTree(TreeNode* root) {`
>          `if (root == nullptr) return nullptr;`
>          `invertTree(root->left);`
>          `invertTree(root->right);`
>          `TreeNode* temp = root->left;`
>          `root->left = root->right;`
>          `root->right = temp;`
>          `return root;`
>      `}`

Comment: ok got it. yea it should be dfs2 and now i realised that my code will only work if my tree is symmetric. the code which you posted , i understood every bit of it. we are recursively swapping the left and right from the bottom and that is how it works. thanks for the help sir.